# How to get my components to resize properly with JFrame Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, layout-manager, designer

I'm trying to make all my components to resize properly with JFrame Netbeans, but if I put the auto resizing to my components, it has like a margin between them, and if I try to put them together, it messes up the components , and I need them to be touching each other.
Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Best to get your hands dirty and use the layout managers. There are several that can be useful for you, even including some 3rd party ones if need be, and complex layouts can be achieved using nested JPanels each using a simple layout manager. For better help, please show your [mre] code.

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score -1):

Double-click on the extra space between the components: it should open a dialog where you can change its size.

You can also click the extra space, and use the mouse wheel.

Netbeans form designer is very powerful and handy when you master it, but it requires some effort at first, especially for large user interfaces. If not already done, take some time to follow this tutorial: https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html

Also, if your user interface is large, it's better to break it in several smaller panels. You can design each panel independently with the form designer.